# How to use WinSCP commands to get multiple files with different ending name

Tags: sftp, winscp

Trying to connect to SFTP connection where there are few CSV files placed in folders and want to download multiple files at once

The directory is `exports/payroll_exports`.

There are 3 files there for now:

```
vani_payroll_bayshore_21323_232.csv 
vani_payroll_bayshore_21344_256.csv 
vani_payroll_bayshore_124523_888.csv
```

How to use a `get` command where I can write `get vani_payroll_bayshore%.csv`?

I plan to add the `get` command to a script like this:

```
option batch on
option confirm off
open sftp:.... -hostkey= "...."
cd exports/payroll_exports
lcd  "\\....."
get ( don't know how to write the wildcard syntax)
close 
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP uses the common file wildcard syntax as most other applications.

To match *anything of any length*, use `*`.

```
get vani_payroll_bayshore*.csv
```

See [WinSCP masks documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

Comment: Thank you so much @martin prikryl